# sample complexity vs training cost (time complexity)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, sample-size, time-complexity

I have a question about the complexities.

Consider two regression problems A, B and assume that A has lower sample complexity than B. A and B share the same target function but the loses are slightly different, so the sample complexity are different.

If I train a neural network (or any kind of suitable learner) to solve A and B with everything fixed (including sample size), and assume my dataset is large enough to solve both A and B.

In this setting, can I expect more efficient training for the problem A? I mean, I want to say that the number of iterations needed to achieve certain accuracy is lower in case of A than in B since the sample complexity is lower. Is this statement true??

Any kind of references would be helpful! I'm kind of new to this field :D

Comment: what is sample complexity?

Comment: @HaitaoDu Sample complexity is a problem of deciding how much training data is needed for a specific training task. You can refer to this article: [How Do You Know You Have Enough Training Data?](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-do-you-know-you-have-enough-training-data-ad9b1fd679ee).